What filter is used by authorizeHttpRequest.anyRequest().authenicated()?
This is my SecurityConfig class, even though my custom filter: SettingsAPIAuthFilter successfully authenticates the request, it returns a 403 due to :
    .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.anyRequest()
                    .authenticated())

I simply extend OncePerRequestFiler in the SettingsAPIAuthFilter class. Here is my SecurityConfig class.
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {


@Autowired
private SettingsAPIAuthFilter settingsAPIAuthFilter;

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    return httpSecurity
            .formLogin(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .httpBasic(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .addFilterBefore(settingsAPIAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .cors(corsConfigurer -> corsConfigurer.configurationSource(request -> {
                CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
                corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("*"));
                corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(List.of(HttpMethod.GET.name(), "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"));
                corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
                return corsConfiguration;
            }))
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.anyRequest()
                    .authenticated())
            .build();

}

}

I would like to know what filter should I extend so that it gets properly authenticated and that authentication is properly picked up by spring security by anyRequest().authenticated()?
EDIT: This is my SettingsAPIAuthFilter :
@Component
public class SettingsAPIAuthFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

private static final String API_AUTHORISE_REQ_ACTION_ID_QUERY_PARAM = "requestActionId";

private static final String API_AUTH_REQ_SESSION_ID_HEADER_NAME = "userSessionId";

public static final String MAIN_API_AUTHORISE_ENDPOINT = "/authorise";

private final AppEventHandler appEventHandler = new AppEventHandler();

private final WebClient mainApiWebClient;

public SettingsAPIAuthFilter(
        @Qualifier("mainApiWebClient") WebClient webClient
) {
    this.mainApiWebClient = webClient;
}

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        ResponseEntity authResponse = authoriseRequest(
                request.getHeader("userSessionId"),
                "123");

        if (authResponse.getStatusCode().value() == 200) {
            appEventHandler.info("Authorisation successful. Moving on...");
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }

        response.setStatus(authResponse.getStatusCode().value());
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        response.getOutputStream().print((String) authResponse.getBody());

    } catch (Exception exception) {
        appEventHandler.error("Error occurred in SettingsAPIAuthFilter", exception);
    }
}

public ResponseEntity<?> authoriseRequest(
        String sessionId,
        String requestedActionId
) throws Exception {
    try {
        return mainApiWebClient.get()
                .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                        .path(MAIN_API_AUTHORISE_ENDPOINT)
                        .queryParam(API_AUTHORISE_REQ_ACTION_ID_QUERY_PARAM, requestedActionId)
                        .build()
                )
                .header(API_AUTH_REQ_SESSION_ID_HEADER_NAME, sessionId)
                .retrieve()
                .onStatus(HttpStatusCode::isError, errorResponse -> Mono.empty())
                .toEntity(String.class)
                .block();

    } catch (Exception exception) {
        appEventHandler.error("Exception occurred in authorising request : ", exception);
        throw new Exception("Exception occurred in authorising request : ", exception);
    }
}
}


The reason was because I was not letting spring security know that the request is authenticated after successful authentication from the authAPI. The fixed was to set authentication to the SecurityContext as follows taken from the spring security documentation:
  Authentication authentication = new TestingAuthenticationToken("user", "password", "ROLE_USER");
            SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
            securityContext.setAuthentication(authentication);

            SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);

Many thanks to @dur for the help. Spring Security Documentation
